# TFS 2015 Rest Api - query parameters ignored and not filtering builds?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Is there a bug in the REST api for TFS 2015 update 3 where it doesn't actually filter when when querying builds?

E.g. I run the below query and get 1000 results
http://myservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/myproject/_apis/build/builds

I run the following and get the same results
http://myservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/myproject/_apis/build/builds?definitionId=thisdefinitiondoesnotexist

And the same using top still returns 1000 results
http://myservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/myproject/_apis/build/builds?top=5

etc etc

It appears none of the filters are being applied - why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the query **exactly following the syntax** for the REST API. Otherwise it will automatically ignore the invalid parameters which behind the valid one, and just run the valid part.

**Get a list of builds:**

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version={version}[&definitions={string}][&queues={string}][&buildNumber={string}][&type={string}][&minFinishTime={DateTime}][&maxFinishTime={DateTime}][&requestedFor={string}][&reasonFilter={string}][&statusFilter={string}][&tagFilters={string}][&propertyFilters={string}][&$top={int}][&continuationToken={string}]
```

**The second query should be:** (It's "**definitions=**" but not definitionId=)

`GET http://myservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/myproject/_apis/build/builds?definitions= {specify definition ID eg: 25,26,27}`
It will response `"count": 0`, If the specified definition id does not exist.

**The third query should be:** (Add **$** before "top" )

```
GET http://myservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/myproject/_apis/build/builds?$top=5
```

Please see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds for using the build REST API.

Comment: Interesting. Will try again with api version 2.0 or 3.0-preview and see if the definitions parameter works. I was reading the api v1 documentation which uses definitionId....

Comment: @PhilLee The [api v1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/xamlbuild/builds) is only available for the version of TFS before 2015 (Xaml build system), for TFS 2015 or later version you need to use api V2.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works well not using the syntax you provided :-)